# pip install Flask does not work in my environment

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I am running: `pip install Flask==1.0.2`

This is happening in **Windows 10** with **python 3.7** installed. I also have **Pycharm** installed.

[image]

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\josevina.corpdom\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\six-1.11.0.dist-info\METADATA'

Environment variables have been set for **JAVA_HOME** to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin`

Comment: Have you succesfully installed any other package that way?

Comment: No @DonQuiKong, I have not been able to install any other package this way or any other way.

Comment: Can you try? It might not be a problem with flask but with your environment. go for something standard, numpy or sth like that.

Comment: Just tried to install numpy and getting the same problem.

Comment: Try reinstalling your environment or deleting (make a copy first!) the "\six-1.11.0.dist-info" folder.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by deleting the contents of the following folder.

> C:\Users\josevina.CORPDOM\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages